# Apart from editing posts, what are the other activities that the community bot is allowed to perform?

Tags: support, community-user

We often find the Community Bot editing posts and making them active again.

I am curious to know, besides that, what are the other activities that it is allowed to perform.

For example i want  to know answers for the following questions:

1) Can it post questions, answers and comments?

2) Can it cast votes on posts and comments?

3) Can it cast votes-to-close and reopen votes?

4) Can it flag posts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Its profile](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile) explains following:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users
> - [Remove abandoned questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006)

Also, there is an answer on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user/19739#19739) that add following extra points:

> - Owns tag wikis, privilege wikis, FAQ/about wikis, and election wikis
> - Rejects suggested edits which may involve edit conflicts
> - [Approves or rejects a suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992/) when a reviewer chooses to submit their own edit
> - Flags smelly stuff for moderators and/or [reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/)
> - Owns certain meta posts, including site evaluation and election meta posts
> - Owns bounties from deleted users
> - Owns up/down votes from [very active deleted users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed)
> - Locks and deletes spam posts
> - Locks migrated posts and rejected migrations
> - [Owns the close vote when an asker agrees with a pending duplicate close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930)
> - [Update image urls from `http` to `https`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291947/roadmap-to-https-serving-and-uploading-https-images-only)

Now, coming to your questions one by one:

## Can it post questions, answers and comments?

No, it doesn't post questions and answers on main site. Although, some users can it asks questions on behalf of Community user on meta sites (graduate) related to [moderator election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158803/why-has-community-started-asking-questions). And it owns certain meta posts, including site evaluation and election meta posts.

## Can it cast votes on posts and comments?

No, it doesn't cast votes on posts and comments. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230610/why-does-the-community-user-have-votes-cast) is the detailed explanation of uv and down votes owned by community user.

> There are a few automatic downvotes, which get attributed to the community user.
>
> - Spam/offensive flags add a downvote
> - Questions closed for certain reasons *used to* get an auto-downvote. They no longer do, but the old ones are probably counted in the totals you see.
> - Very Low Quality flags that are dismissed as helpful trigger an automatic downvote.
>
> Normally when a user is deleted, their votes are deleted as well. However, in exceptional cases, i.e. when removing all their votes would be disruptive to the community, their votes are transferred to the community user so they aren't deleted with the account. That most likely accounts for the upvotes.

## Can it cast votes-to-close and reopen votes?

No, It doesn't vote to close/reopen. Instead, it [owns the close vote when an asker agrees with a pending duplicate close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930)

## Can it flag posts?

Yes. It flags smelly stuff for moderators and/or [reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/).

Comment: Community doesn't post questions. Usually Pops or Jon Ericson post elections announcements. Those were rare cases where a user(moderator) chose to post behalf of community. Flagging is not normal flagging like we do. It identifies spam post which we see in reviews "Our system identified this post as spam. Please review carefully."  That's flagging done by system.

Comment: Thanks. That's a very comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Rickross You are welcome. Glad it helps.

Comment: @Sinister Edited answer regarding asking questions. In case of flagging, we can say "flagged by community".

Comment: Flagged by community doesn't mean flagged by community bot. Community refers to the users(us). See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) glossary.

Comment: @Sinister The flags from deleted users are assigned to Community User but there are also ten types of flags that are system generated and only seen to Moderators. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203061/why-are-there-moderator-flags-from-the-community-user-and-what-are-they-for)