# Who has access to Community user and how is it accessed?

Tags: support, community-user

Who has access to the  rules that decide Community user's participation and how frequently are they edited. Who edits them?

Comment: Related [Apart from editing posts, what are the other activities that the community bot is allowed to perform?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/962/apart-from-editing-posts-what-are-the-other-activities-that-the-community-bot-i) not duplicate.

Comment: @Triyugi This question is [answered](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/963/277).

Comment: Thank you @TriyugiNarayanMani and pandya I am interested in knowing answers to Qs 3 and 4. These Q are not addressed by the other Q. Hence it may not be a duplicate.

Comment: @moonstar Can you please remove first two points?

Comment: @moonstar I think first three questions are answered as 1) points that are mentioned in it's profile and 2) points mentioned from [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/260388) ("it also..."). Talking about 4th question, it sounds different (not asked earlier). You may highlight/limit question for that only and revise title accordingly. Btw, I think only StackExchange developer or team has access to edit rules of community user.

Comment: @Pandya - I am not so sure. I see this Community bot bumping up Qs of mostly a certain user or two. The bot is not universally randomized.

Comment: @moonstar No, not at all. You can check [its all actions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=all) to investigate.

Comment: I also get the same impression sometimes like what @moonstar got but it may not be true.

Comment: @Pandya et al - edited. Please reopen.

Comment: @moonstar regarding the bumping of old unanswered question, it's answered on [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/241919): "*Note that the posts (read: questions) eligible for bumping are those scoring >= 0 that have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be deleted or closed).*"