# In what scenarios 'Community' user cast a close as duplicate vote?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

From some meta posts, it seems that 'Community' user doesn't cast close as duplicate vote automatically. When a normal user cast a close as duplicate vote and then OP approves it (or cast vote, not sure), the Q gets closed by the name of first user and Community user (instead of OP). Is this correct understanding? And if so, there seems no reasons to again open the Q as OP has already approved the duplicate (saying this solves my problem [from, meta it seems he has to click on this button]).

But still I see that some Q's were opened  after it was closed by me and Community (or OP in real sense).

And then OP commented, **why this Q is opened again?** And [reply](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28996/do-our-scriptures-give-way-to-reduce-or-cross-over-prarabdha-karma#comment86272_28996):  "You don't want it to be reopened? Some users thought that it shd be closed that's why it got closed. Now some other users thought it shd be reopened. So five of them cast their reopen votes and it is reopened." But if OP himself approved duplicate then it's obvious that he doesn't want to open it again and "Some users thought that it shd be closed", here some users include OP. So, is our community aware of this scenario when Q is closed as duplicate by 'Community' user?

---

Meta posts I m referring to:

[Apart from editing posts, what are the other activities that the community bot is allowed to perform?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/962/apart-from-editing-posts-what-are-the-other-activities-that-the-community-bot-i/963#963)

[Can we clarify to the OP that their question is not yet closed and the duplicates are only suggestions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930)

Comment: Deleted that...I was editing and it created new Q..u can report it as bug.. @TheDestroyer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the understanding is correct. Community user closes a question only when the OP has selected the question as duplicate. It means the *OP is satisfied with the suggestion and found the answer to his question* which was already present on the site.

There is no need of reopening those questions because the OP themselves are happy with the questions and answers found by the users. Only cases where we need to do reopen

1. When the close vote is casted in a hurry i.e., both the questions have *no relation* at all. For E.g :[Conditions for changing sacred thread?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17581/5212) closed as a duplicate of [On what occasions can sacred thread be worn around the neck like garland?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23480/5212)
2. When the OP chose it in a hurry i.e without knowing what is it. We see such instances during suggested edit reviews. It normally happens when the OP is a new user.

Reviews like close voting and reopening are not like votes which solely depend on the choice of the user (in fact, there are guidelines when to upvote and downvote a post but that is not followed by many). So, five users cannot close or reopen just because they thought it is a duplicate or it is not. The answers should be satisfy the OP and regarding that, *OP's vote matters than other users*.. that is the reason the **OP is given binding vote for duplicates** and not for off-topic, primarily opinion based or too broad questions. Perhaps the users were not aware that OP is the one of the users who close voted it and was really satisfied with the questions and answers. That satisfaction is shown again, it is closed yet again by the OP himself with another duplicate. If you find another duplicate and not the one OP selected or more than one duplicate questions which answer the OP's question, you can ask a moderator to modify the list of duplicates rather than reopening the question and closing the question again. It is an abuse of the our close voting and reopening privilege.