# Why is this question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40266/20829 marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

This question on [roots of Karma Yoga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40266/20829) is not the same as the [question on "law of Karma"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/origin-of-the-law-of-karma). The former is about selfless action without desire for specific results. The latter is about the inferential law of "cause and effect" of individual actions.

How does one message a moderator or request to reopen the question?

Comment: Yes origin of law of karma and karma yoga.. are different things.. Question needs to be reopened!...

Comment: I changed the title to "What is the origin of Nishkama Karma (selfless action)?" so users don't mistake it as dup. of the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the given question is reopened. You can check [timeline](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/40266/timeline) of the given question for the same.

**What we can do when we see a question is closed as duplicate but it shouldn't be?**

> Cast "reopen" vote.

**Who can cast reopen vote?**

> Any user with 500+ reputation can cast close/reopen vote. Below that reputation, a user can flag.

To know all the privileges based on reputation, check this link:

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: Related: [Ways to reopen a question?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1760/17010)